# Post to URL vales via c# code behind

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to make a universal log-in page that takes a redirectPage that the login information actually gets submitted to.

The flow of the app is like so:

1. Take in username and login and do my own authentication
2. Once authenticated, I retrieve 2 unrelated variables( varA, varB )
3. Now I need to submit varA and varB to the redirectPage via post. I'm not wanting to do session variables or querystring. I'm wanting to do redirect and post just like if you were posting from a form.

What I've seen so far on SO is where the client is just posting and getting a repsonse. I don't care about a response I want to also redirect to this page.

Comment: you want to do it only via C#?

Comment: If there's another way, I'm open to suggestions. This is a ASP .Net/ C# project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will cost a roundtrip(as `Response.Redirect()` does), but it's a sane way of doing what you want.

```
public void ReirectPost(string redirectUrl, Dictionary<string,string> vars)
{
  Response.Clear();

  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  sb.Append("<html>");
  sb.AppendFormat(@"<body onload='document.forms[""form""].submit()'>");
  sb.AppendFormat("<form name='form' action='{0}' method='post'>", redirectUrl);
  foreach(var v in vars)
    sb.AppendFormat("<input type='hidden' name='{0}' value='{1}'>", v.Key, v.Value);

  sb.Append("</form></body></html>");

  Response.Write(sb.ToString());
  Response.End();
}
```